# MomentJS : Date comparison with moment

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I want to compare dates so I get the dates and then use moment to get it into a certain format-before comparing it with the date in my database.

Here is the code where I format my date into certain format to compare it later.

```
var date = req.body.validFrom;
var formatDate = moment(date, "MM-DD-YYYY");
console.log(date);
```

But I am getting an output as an object given below, so I don't know how should I compare my dates? Can anyone tell me why I am getting this output and how should I format it? I tried all combinations but it gives me this object.

```
    { [Number: 1492626600000]
  _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: Sat Jan 16 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
  _f: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
  _isUTC: false,
  _pf:
   { empty: false,
     unusedTokens: [],
     unusedInput: [ 'Sat Jan ', ' ', ' 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' ],
     overflow: 1,
     charsLeftOver: 49,
     nullInput: false,
     invalidMonth: null,
     invalidFormat: false,
     userInvalidated: false,
     iso: false },
  _locale:
   Locale {
     _ordinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
     ordinal: [Function],
     _abbr: 'en',
     _ordinalParseLenient: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/ },
  _d: Thu Apr 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) }
POST /admin/schedules/ - - ms - -
2016-01-15T18:30:00.000Z
{ [Number: 1492626600000]
  _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: Sat Jan 16 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
  _f: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
  _isUTC: false,
  _pf:
   { empty: false,
     unusedTokens: [],
     unusedInput: [ 'Sat Jan ', ' ', ' 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' ],
     overflow: 1,
     charsLeftOver: 49,
     nullInput: false,
     invalidMonth: null,
     invalidFormat: false,
     userInvalidated: false,
     iso: false },
  _locale:
   Locale {
     _ordinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
     ordinal: [Function],
     _abbr: 'en',
     _ordinalParseLenient: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/ },
  _d: Thu Apr 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
var formatDate = moment(date).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
console.log(formatDate);
```

You need to create the moment object based on the date and then format it.

I'm not sure if you mean to log `date` or `formatDate` as well.

Answer (score 1):

To use moment to return a string value you need to call `.format(format)` [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

So in your case I believe it should be

```
var date = req.body.validFrom;
var formatDate = moment(date).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
console.log(formatDate);
```

Comment: Up votes always appreciated for answers that work. :)